# I can't get records from a stored procedure

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I can't get records from a stored procedure. If I run from SQL Server, I get records. If I call it from .NET, I get records... but if I call it from PHP, I don't get records.

I am using PHP 5.3.3 on CentOS 6. I am using mssql. All others SP are ok.

I tried

```
$provider = 1010;
$array = array();
$stmt2 = mssql_init("[dbo].[PORA_sp_GET_LetterGenerationRecords]");
mssql_bind($stmt2, "@ProviderID", $provider, SQLINT4);
$letters = mssql_execute($stmt2);
while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($letters)){
    $array[] = $row;
}
mssql_free_statement($stmt2);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($array); echo '</pre>';
```

and I have

```
Array
(
)
```

I tried too

```
$array = array();
$letters = mssql_query('EXEC [dbo].[PORA_sp_GET_LetterGenerationRecords] @ProviderID = 1010');
while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($letters)){
    $array[] = $row;
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($array); echo '</pre>';
```

and I got

```
Array
(
)
```

I included

```
echo 'MSSQL error: '. mssql_get_last_message();
```

and the answer:

```
MSSQL error:
```

I am very curious. Right now I am running the SP step by step from PHP. It's a shameful.

I tried:

```
    $provider = 1010;
    $array = array();
//    $letters = mssql_query('EXEC [dbo].[PORA_sp_GET_LetterGenerationRecords] @ProviderID = 1010');
    $stmt2 = mssql_init("[dbo].[PORA_sp_GET_LetterGenerationRecords]");
    mssql_bind($stmt2, "@ProviderID", $provider, SQLINT4);
    $letters = mssql_execute($stmt2);
    if($letters){
        echo mssql_num_rows($letters);
        while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($letters)){
            $array[] = $row;
        }
        mssql_free_statement($stmt2);
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($array); echo '</pre>';
    }
    else{
        echo 'MSSQL error: '. mssql_get_last_message();

        echo error_get_last();
    }
```

and same answer.

Comment: So if you do a `SELECT * FROM whatever` in PHP using the same code, it returns a result set?

Comment: When I run everything in PHP, run ok. This SP is complicated, because is taking data from some tables and creating a temporal table with the  data.

Comment: And just to clarify, if you execute `EXEC [dbo].[PORA_sp_GET_LetterGenerationRecords] @ProviderID = 1010` in management studio or whatever, it works fine? (rather than executing the code within the procedure)

Comment: Yes. And if I call the SP from .NET, it works fine too.

Comment: To avoid confusion, in the last example (the one begins with $provider = 1010;) you're missing an 's' on the if. $letters vs $letter. I don't know if $letter is ok but out of scope.

Comment: You are right. The answer is 
    Array
    (
    )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks fine but for some reason the sql statement is being terminated.

So you need to debug this,I would suggest first try to get it to work with the parameter hard coded:

```
try {
    $array = array();
    $result = mssql_query('EXEC [dbo].[PORA_sp_GET_LetterGenerationRecords] @ProviderID = 1010');
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $array[] = $row;
    }
    var_dump($array);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    error_log($e->getMessage());// or log it to a txt file
    echo 'MSSQL error: '. mssql_get_last_message();
    echo 'Last error: '.error_get_last();

}
```

---

You should also run SQL profiler and filter on the exception to have a better idea.

Comment: I did it. The answer is array(0) { }

Comment: what can be the cause why a sql statement is being terminated?

Comment: @EmilioGort the error itslef is not so meaning full as it could be due to different things.

Comment: I created a different template in order to find errors using SQL Profiler. I got it:
sql Error: 515, Severity: 16, State: 2

I searched columns for NULL data, and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $query = "EXEC [dbo].[PORA_sp_GET_LetterGenerationRecords] @ProviderID = 1010";
   $result = mssql_query($query);
   if (!$result) {
       die('Invalid query: ' . mssql_error());
   }

   while ($row = @mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['col1']
   }
?>
```

Comment: I made

    $query = "EXEC [dbo].[PORA_sp_GET_LetterGenerationRecords] @ProviderID = 1010";
   $result = mssql_query($query);
   if (!$result) {
       die('Invalid query: ' . mssql_error());
   }
   echo mssql_num_rows($result);
   while ($row = @mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['ID'];
   }

and the result: 0